Why did Israel invade the Gaza strip from the north and not the south?
Given Israel's stated goal in the war is destruction of Hamas, why did they attack the Gaza strip from the North instead of from the South? The latter seems more sensible since taking Rafah first would trap Hamas' fighters against the Mediterranean. By attacking from the North instead, Hamas' fighters could conceivably flee via Egypt.
I'm looking for any public statements about this by Israeli officials, if any have been made; or an explanation why this would not make military sense.

Egypt's present government considers Hamas an offshoot of the Muslim Brotherhood, so very bad people. Also, they've sent their own tanks to the border, which may have a dual purpose, but many interpreted as being insurance against any moves by the Palestinians. So the premise of the Q that Hamas could flee to Egypt is pretty questionable. (In any case, the IDF took the Rafah border crossing today or yesterday.)

Isreal would love for Hamas to become an Egyptian problem....

Military reasons
Northern Gaza poses more direct threat - notably in terms of firing rockets at Israeli communities or carrying the attacks, like that of October 7 (see the map below). Indeed, most of the territory on the same longitude as Gaza is the sparsely populated Negev desert - Beersheba being the most populated place with about 200,000 inhabitants. Tel Aviv, Jerusalem and other highly populated towns are to the north of Gaza.
(image source)

Likewise, the north of Gaza is densely populated (notably the Gaza City), and likely to contain most of Hamas' infrastructure:

Humanitarian reasons
Invading from the north also allowed civilians to flee to the south of Gaza, which borders with Egypt. This would enable to those, having Egyptian passports and visas to exit the strip. It would also allowed resupplying the strip via Egypt, rather than via the crossing points in Israel, which are most vulnerable to the attacks - in fact, this is how it was during the first weeks of the war.
Some would also add that this could have allowed potential expulsion of Gazans to Egypt - the idea was publicly discussed by some extreme right wing ministers, but it is not clear whether it had ever affected the military planning.
Political reasons
Invasion of Rafah, particularly the Philadelphi corridor is problematic in view of the relations between Israel and Egypt, which assume demilitarization of the areas near the border, as a guarantee of non-agression by both sides (or being able to detect the preparations for such an aggression well in advance.) Indeed, it took some haggling between Israel and Egypt, before Egypt tacitly accepted that it would not abrogate the peace treaty between the two countries, if Israel invades Rafah (see, e.g., here and here.)

Presumably there are also logistical reasons with the north being easier to supply; Wikipedia has this map of Israeli military bases, and from a road map, main Israeli roads like Highway 4 run to the northern end of Gaza while the south is less well-connected.

This map of Hamas underground compounds released by the IDF confirms that most of Hamas infrastructure was concentrated in Northern Gaza.

Another reason not mentioned in the other answers is the force distribution of Hamas. Most of Hamas's battalions (about 75%) and operations are in the central and northern areas of the strip, mainly Gaza City and Khan-Yunis. By attacking in Gaza City first, they strike at the heart of Hamas, eliminating a large number of its regiments and its HQs, as was found under Al-Shifa hospital. In the Khan-Yunis sector, there was a Hamas large intelligence center under UNRWA's server station.
To contrast, Rafah's battalions are weaker and smaller and pose little tactical significance. Rafah is important now also because that's where the hostages were moved to, but intelligence has shown that the hostages were initially brought to Gaza City, which made it even more significant at the start of the war.
To sum it up, it's about the gain compared to the investment of forces. Gaza City and then Khan-Yunis were much more beneficial targets than Rafah.

"its HQs, as was found under Al-Shifa hospital" citation needed. "the Associated Press, the New York Times, the Wall Street Journal, the Guardian, Sky News stated that this did not constitute conclusive evidence to demonstrate the use by Hamas of a command center." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shifa_Hospital#Israeli_media_campaign
